# I would like to know how to convert Spring mvc Java configuration environment

Tags: java, xml, spring, model-view-controller, config

Spring mvc .xml file I want to change the bean configuration to the java config environment during configuration.

dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<bean class="pporan.maven.framework.spring.CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="customArgumentResolvers" ref="eDataArgumentResolver"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="eDataArgumentResolver" class="pporan.maven.framework.spring.EDataArgumentResolver"/>
```

CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class file content

```
public class CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter implements RequestMappingHandlerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.afterPropertiesSet();
       .........             
       setArgumentResolvers(list);
  }
}
```

EDataArgumentResolver.class file content

```
public class EDataArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
            ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
            NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest();
    ......

        return eData;
    }
}

  @Override
  public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
      return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(EData.class);
  }
}
```

I made it like this one by one.

I want to know how to do this in the java config environment

Comment: what have you tried in particular that hasn't worked? you are just showing us the Servlet xml context and two bean definitions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't had the time to actually try it out , but you should be able to do sthg like this:

```
@Configuration
public YourConfigClass {

    ...

    @Bean
    public HandlerMethodArgumentResolver eDataArgumentResolver() {
        return new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
            @Override
            public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
                parameter.getParameterType().equals(EData.class);
            }

            @Override
            public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest();

                [...]

                return eData;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(final HandlerMethodArgumentResolver eDataArgumentResolver) {
        final RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setCustomArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(eDataArgumentResolver));
        return requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
    }
}
```

Would be great to let me know whether it works or not!

Comment: @user3648971 you're welcome. I'm glad I was able to help!